# Can't use localhost as request URL, instead I have to use ip address

Tags: http, request, httpresponse

I've been working on a web site, and I'm constantly making API requests, but when I try to do it with localhost:5000, it just won't work, instead of that, I am forced to  have to use my IP address which is a bit annoying because I move constantly, can please someone help me with this?

Error:

[image: Error when using localhost]

With IP Address:

[image: response when using IP address]

I've been searching but I've seen some people who has my problem in reverse, so I haven't tried too many things, that's why I'm asking here.